# Use specific font in LyX

Tags: fonts, lyx

I would like to use some of theese greek fonts in LyX for my thesis:
http://aka-acid.com/fontsscript.html

I installed the theme but I don't know how to use it in LyX

I also installed XeTeX

Can someone who uses LyX, guide me step by step?

Comment: By 'theme' do you mean the font? (And, as an aside, I would *beseech* you *not* to use these fonts in your thesis... it is your decision of course, but imho they don't look professional.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert but I just spent a lot of time figuring this out myself.

In LyX go to document settings. Under fonts, check use XeTeX fonts, and pick your fonts.
You should be good to go.

If you want, or that doesn't work, you can also put the following in your preamble:

```
\setmainfont{nameofyourinstalledfont} %set font for main document
```

This will override the setting above.

If you want to change this at any time in your document, just insert an ERT with:

```
\setmainfont{nameofnewinstalledfont} %set new font for main document
```

You can also use `fontspec` e.g.
`\fontspec[Numbers=OldStyle]{Bergamo Std}`

It depends on where you want to go...

Answer (score 0):

Everyone starting with LyX takes too long working out that LyX does not display installed fonts (Currrently LyX only display the LaTeX fonts programmed into the menu) and that you have to use the above kludge using LaTeX.

If you want to make a LaTeX appear in your LyX menu check out
http://lyx.475766.n2.nabble.com/Making-STIX-appear-in-LyX-Document-gt-Settings-gt-Fonts-tt7580330.html

Comment: The sentence "If you want to make a LaTeX appear in your LyX menu..." is quite unclear, to me at least. Please edit your posting to clarify its meaning. Please also consider providing the gist of the linked message in the answer itself: Over time, links do tend to get broken, making any links-only answers useless. Thanks.